# How to extract the second set of data from my split list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to loop through this text file, split up the text and extract the data for the high and low temps into 2 separate lists:
I have the following code which gives me the High temps but I am stuck on what I am missing to get the low temps. Could someone please explain where I am going wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
high =[]
low =[]
line =''

inFile = open('julyTemps.txt')

for line in inFile:
    fields = line.split(' ')

with open ('julyTemps.txt') as inFile:
    if fields != 3 or 'Boston' == fields[0] or 'Day' == fields[0]:
        high = (line.split(' ')[1:2] for line in inFile)
        high =[item[0] for item in high if item]
        high = ','.join([i for i in high if i.isdigit()])
with open ('julyTemps.txt') as inFile:
    if fields != 3 or 'Boston' == fields[0] or 'Day' == fields[0]:
        low = (line.split(' ')[2:2] for line in inFile)
        low = [item[0] for item in low if item]
        low =','.join([i for i in low if i.isdigit()])
```

txtfile:

```
Boston July Temperatures
-------------------------

Day High Low
------------

1 91 70
2 84 69
3 86 68
4 84 68
5 83 70
6 80 68
7 86 73
8 89 71
9 84 67
10 83 65
11 80 66
12 86 63
13 90 69
14 91 72
15 91 72 
16 88 72
17 97 76
18 89 70
19 74 66
20 71 64
21 74 61
22 84 61
23 86 66
24 91 68
25 83 65
26 84 66
27 79 64
28 72 63
29 73 64
30 81 63
31 73 63
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the file in one, adding the lows and highs to two separate lists:

```
lows, highs = [], []
with open ('julyTemps.txt') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        try:
            day, low, high = map(int, line.split())
        except ValueError:
            continue  # no temps on this line
        lows.append(low)
        highs.append(high)
```

We only look at lines that have 3 integer values, the rest would throw a `ValueError`, either because there are not 3 values on the line or because there are non-integer values. These lines are ignored.

Comment: That's really quick- thanks very much for your help. I can see why this code is better than mine- I'm learning all the time!